# Output MP3 file with PHP after communication with DB

Tags: php, header, mp3, content-type

I have a website that allows users to play MP3's, but I want to know how many times each file is played. I've tried searching to see how to output an MP3 with PHP, and I thought you could do it with a call to `header('Content-Type')` but I can't find any documentation on it.

Let's say I have a file, `/music/song.mp3`, and I have the DB interaction code done and no output has been sent to the browser, what headers would I need to pass to allow the MP3 to output once I've finished with my DB interactions?

Update:
Here is what I'm using now, and the page downloads an mp3 with the correct filename, but it's corrupted and won't play. Any idea why that is?

```
$track = $_GET['t'];
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'music/'.$track.'.mp3'));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$track.'.mp3"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");
```

Here is a link where you can test the mp3:
http://shacktown.com/engine/api/mp3/?t=giftofmelody

Answer (score 0):

Your [`header`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) should look something like this:

```
$file = "/some/folder/your.mp3";

header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="your.mp3"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary"); 
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg, audio/x-mpeg, audio/x-mpeg-3, audio/mpeg3");

readfile($file);
```

Comment: For filename, should I include the entire path to the file?

Comment: @danL No, just the filename the user/browser should see.

Comment: @danL That is not an updated question, thats more like a second question. How do you read your file from the database and output the content?

Comment: The file is stored in an mp3, not stored in the DB itself. I can open another question if that's necessary. Should $yourmp3file be a file_get_contents() reference to the mp3?

Comment: @danL I was asking how yo output the content, because this wasn't described yet. To explain this further, I've added a trivial output example to the code mentioned in my answer. Please have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just recording the information to the DB and then forwarding to the source file. I tried your updated example but just can't get the file to read properly. In case anyone was wondering, this is the code I'm using now, and functionally it works as desired.

```
$trackPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'music/'.$track.'.mp3';
if ( !file_exists($trackPath) )
    die('no!');
$trackInfo = $db->Fetch('tracks', 'plays', 'src="'.$track.'"');
$update = $db->Update('tracks', array('plays'=>$trackInfo['plays']+1), 'src="'.$track.'"');
header('Location: http://shacktown.com/music/'.$track.'.mp3');
```

$db is shorthand for a DB object I made for easy querying, but I think it's pretty self explanatory.